# How to write a script to assign adobe reader as the default application for opening PDFs on Android?

Tags: default-applications

I am distributing locked down tablets to my employees, ~40.

Right now, one application opens a PDF and the user is presented with multiple PDF readers to choose from. This could cause confusion (I know.. I know..).

The two solutions I have come up with are:

1. Write a script that assigns a default PDF reader for the user
2. Uninstall all of the other PDF readers (Both AT&T and T-Mobile have their own PDF readers and we may add other carriers with however many PDF readers.) (Could I write a script to uninstall the other PDF readers?)

Are these solutions viable with Android? If so, I would love to here solutions!

Thanks

Note:
I am not using the devices and I do not have physical access to them. The users of this device boot into a locked down home page with an Icon for 'manual' that opens a PDF. The users cannot change anything about the device. They can't open settings, Can't open a browser, etc. Nothing.

Right now, the users in the field are being presented with the option to use 2 or 3 separate PDF readers. I want all of my users using the same reader so that I can test the usability of the PDF.

Because I cannot personally access all of the devices ( we push updates through Soti Mobile), I want to deploy a script that forces the device to use Adboe reader

Comment: FYI: holding down the menu button while booting starts the device in safe mode where the user can access anything. Just like without a lock.

Comment: Hmmmmm well Soti should be forcing the device into a locked down state. I'll have to test this.

Comment: Development questions are off-topic here. Ask at [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Hahaha! I have been told otherwise at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913465/how-to-write-a-script-to-assign-adobe-reader-as-the-default-application-for-open#comment12650850_9913465

Comment: :D Really laughing situation. Actually, they are wrong. The script needs to interact with API of Android.

Comment: Any more guidance you can give?

Comment: What you added lately as `Note`, add that at SO. Without it, question looks like normal question to which I answered.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that it's more than likely that the default PDF readers are system applications so removing them is not an option without root access (which is not viable because it would make it even easier to bypass security)

Comment: Do most tablets from a provider not allow root access? If they do, I should be able to get root access.

Comment: No it's not allowed by default, in fact it may not even void the warranty. Plus it could be a big security risk on kiosk/locked down devices.

Comment: I think option 2 may be your best bet.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is totally off-topic.  We've covered shell scripts for users to accomplish tasks before, and this isn't that much different.  However, you need to stop cross-posting.  Keep it on one site -- the SO question is still open so I'm closing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a deprecated api which allows to set preferred activities for specific intents. So you could for example set the adobe reader as the preferred activity to start when "open pdf" intent is sent

However as it states this api is deprecated so it could be removed in future versions of android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPreferredActivity(android.content.IntentFilter, int, android.content.ComponentName[], android.content.ComponentName)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any type of script.
When user is presented with multiple PDF readers to choose from, one can found a checkbox `Use by default for this action` at bottom. Check it & tap Adobe Reader. Done!

[image: PDF Readers]

Comment: That's the thing. I don't want the user to be presented with a default app selection. I want to choose for them. This is for a locked down device, ~40 tablets within my company.

Comment: @ericf What do you mean by locked down device? If you can bother running a script in all devices, you can do this too. Its not a 10-step solution.

Comment: Tick the use by default box like Sachin said.

Comment: I am not using the device. The users of this device boot into a locked down home page with an Icon for 'manual' that opens a PDF. The users cannot change anything about the device. They can't open settings, etc. Nothing. 

Right now, the users in the field are being presented with the option to use 2 or 3 separate PDF readers. I want all of my users using the same reader so that I can test the usability of the PDF. 

Because I cannot personally access all of the devices ( we push updates through Soti Mobile), I want to deploy a script that forces the device to use Adboe reader.

Comment: I am sorry to say, such things are off-topic on this site.

Comment: SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913465/how-to-write-a-script-to-assign-adobe-reader-as-the-default-application-for-open#comment12650850_9913465